# asp mvc event textchanged of textboxfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textchanged, html.textboxfor

I'm an ASP.NET MVC beginner - I want to get user information by entering the user name in a textbox username. Then when I click a tab button or move the mouse away from the textbox username, after the textbox the user's information will be displayed - like the textbox TextChanged event in webforms.

How can this be achieved? Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for the JavaScript [`onblur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onblur) event.

Comment: @Andrei V There is other way without using javascript?

Comment: The only alternative I see is to have a button/link that you'd click after setting the data inside your text boxes. Then you would need to send the data to the server and receive a partial view. Your data would have to be inside an AJAX form. This all seams just to complicated for the task you described. Furthermore, you're using APS.NET MVC, you **need** to learn/use JavaScript/jQuery. You must start somewhere :).